# Drupal 8, Webform module : send html mail with plain text mime/alternative

Tags: html, text, drupal, webforms, multipart

We use Webform Drupal 8 module to handle newsletter subscription on a website. An html formatted email is sent to confirm subscription. Unfortunately, this email is sent with only content-type:text/html, and you know how picky Spamassassin is about this. It's a real deliverability issue.
We'd like to be able to send that email with a content-type:multipart/alternative, with 2 parts : one with text/html content-type and one with text/plain.
How can we do this ? We installed "mail system" and "mime mail" modules, but we can't figure out how to use them, or even if it's the right solution.
Has anyone ever managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/mime-mail/for-developers/providing-an-alternate-plain-text-version-of-an).

Once [mime-mail module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) is enabled you can modify the emails send by Drupal using `hook_mail_alter` hook [(see here)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/8.2.x) and add plain-text version.

In a custom module, in your `mymodule.module` file you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {

  //to specify which email need altering based on id
  //without this all emails send will be altered
  if (isset($message['id']) && $message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail') {
    
    //set plain text
    $message['params']['plaintext']= "HTML support needed";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We implemented hook_mail_alter, it works fine even without a mime-mail module installed.
We also had to implement hook_module_implements_alter to be sure to do the processing after webform.